# What datastructure is the fastest to find the best matching prefix?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, prefix, prefix-tree

Context: I'm working on an analyzer for useragent strings ([Yauaa](https://yauaa.basjes.nl/)) and as part of this analysis I want to make an educated guess what brand of the device should be reported. I have an implementation that I need to rewrite to be a lot more efficient.

Because I do not want to have a complete list of all devices I want to do the detection based on the prefix of the model.

So I have a dataset with prefixes and the brand that is associated:

- "GT-"  --> "Samsung"
- "LLD-" --> "Huawei"

And then I want to do a .get("GT-1234124") which should result in "Samsung" because that is the "longest matching prefix".

I had a look at the Trie structure but that seems to be for the opposite situation. What I understand is that you start with a set of values and you can efficiently get all the values that starts with the provided prefix.

If I were to implement this from scratch I would use a tree similar to the Trie but walk around it differently. What I'm looking for is a datastructure that does what I need as fast as possible.

What datastructure do you recommend for this usecase?

Is there an existing (proven) implementation I can use?

Comment: does 2 brands have similar signature, like are there brand having similar model prefixes?

Comment: In this implementation I have every prefix exactly once.

Comment: by similar signature I meant does it have GT for samsung and say other company XYZ ?

Comment: In this specific usecase there are many things to discuss. Right now I'm focusing on the question of the optimal datastructure to retrieve the desired result: getting the best match against the stored prefixes.

Comment: As you mentioned, stored prefixes can be maintained in trie, but if dataset key(model name) have more unique letters than it can be memory intensive, you can use suffix tree instead using aho-corasick algorithm though its hard to understand.

Comment: key which is model name contains alphabets(both case), numbers, hyphen, thus increasing the branching factor.

Comment: I suggest you can go through [this](https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/needle-in-a-haystack-a-nifty-large-scale-text-search-algorithm) you can split unique key values into them as GT(starting code) , - (hyphen) , alphanumeric, thus giving branching factor of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging into datastructures and found that essentially the Trie structure is what I need with a different way of walking around the structure.

Since this structure is really simple I created my own implementation that works very well.

See: 
https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/master/analyzer/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/utils/PrefixLookup.java

---

Updates:

1. I wrote an article about this https://techlab.bol.com/finding-the-longest-matching-string-prefix-fast/
2. I put my implementation into a separate library which I opensourced and which is already available via maven central. See https://github.com/nielsbasjes/prefixmap

Comment: Great!! Just keep an eye on memory usage, 128 prefixtrie array can grow large, instead ill suggest using set since not all 128 nodes may be filled.

Comment: And may i know what is the performance improvement due to trie implementation, i am curious 

Comment: The first "quick n dirty" was a list of prefixes sorted by length with a "foreach if startsWith" that did 1000000 in 3.7 seconds. This one does 1000000 in 37ms. So about 100 times faster.

Comment: Amazing , power of data structures 